# Kivy sound not looping

Tags: python, loops, audio, kivy

I am fairly new to kivy and python and have been working on an idea for an app for some time now. I would like sound to 'loop' at certain points in the app so I have been experimenting with SoundLoader recently.
Interesting thing is when I first used started using it, sound worked and looped as expected. However, after some additions to implement the sound as I would like I noticed that it no longer loops but rather just plays the sound once. 
I using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and kivy version 1.9.0.
Code I am using for sound:

```
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
tmp=SoundLoader.load('tmp.wav')
tmp.loop = True
tmp.play()
```

Comment: looks a lot like this; https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/2885

Comment: Thanks @Jean-Francois. I will do some more reading on this problem. BTW are there any other cross platform options for playing sound in python? Would like the app to work for both Android and iOS as well.

Answer (score 1):

this can be implemented by using the Clock module to sort of repeat the playing of the sound, i adapted this from the kivy app fast perception..

```
def check_sound(self, dt = None):
        self.sound.play()



from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
tmp=SoundLoader.load('tmp.wav')
tmp.play()
Clock.schedule_interval(self.check_sound, 1)
```

i hope this helps..

Comment: This works likes charm. I love this solution to the problem. Many thanks Joey!